# How to make my app make the mouse disappear in all windows only while my app is running

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm looking for a decent way to make the mouse cursor disappear in all windows (not only my own)- 
this is why Mouse.OverrideCursor isn't what I'm looking for - unless there is way to make another application's mouse disappear in this manner.
I've tried changing the registry keys of the mouse cursors, but this creates a lot of problems if my application gets killed before I can change it back to the original cursors.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT:
I've decided to go with SetSystemCursor, and then going back to normal with SystemParametersInfo.

This seems to solve one of my problems: Unlike hacking the registry, changing it doesn't persist after a hard reboot.

To solve my other problem - if the app has been killed - I can only think of using a watchdog app, which seems to be the only reasonable solution.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I'm writing a custom controller for Windows, and I want to change the cursor completely without using the limited cursor API.

Comment: One question: A what?

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt You move your mouse-> a cursor moves on the screen - thats so 90s'. I'm doing something like this: You move your mouse, something totally radical happens. Custom Controller. was that clear?

Comment: Completely clear. I tend to like the result of me moving the mouse making the cursor move on screen, but then again, I'm from way before the 90's ;)
Good luck!

Comment: The mouse belongs to the system, not to any one application and anything you can do to hide it, any other app could potentially undo, so it's going to be difficult to get a robust result. Although what you've described sounds intriguing, it will be a nightmare to debug ;-)

Comment: @RogerRowland So far - I've only tried to prevent the system getting stuck with a no mouse state (which is the worse kind of bug as far as I'm concerned). As i'm continually changing the mouse back and forth, another app undoing what I did is not my nightmare right now.

Comment: The lack of an appropriate API might quite possibly be an indication that what you're trying to achieve is not readily possible. You're going to be fighting the OS all the way, and lose in the end. Most likely, the totally radical somethings that are going to happen is your app not behaving like it should at best, or, worse, your app causing unpredictable behavior in otherwise perfectly well behaving applications. Your application and all others share the OS. One ring to rule them all doesn't fit in that picture.

Answer (score 0):

I think that either this [ShowCursor](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ShowCursor.html) or this [WNDCLASS](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/WNDCLASS.html) will help you

Comment: from ShowCursor: "This API only affects the mouse cursor when it is over windows created by the same thread which calls it." so thats not it.

Comment: using the WNDCLASS API seems to open a new bag of worms when trying to  communicate with my 32bit app and a 64 bit app. Also, always finding the right window isn't trivial.